# Trim and return specific character set removing rest using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I need some help in returning value from the string below using javascript to use within google sheet.

I need to return 0.3000 from the string below.

```
Bid</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="BID-value" data-reactid="51"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s) " data-reactid="52">0.3000</span>
```

I have tried the following but not getting desired results.
</span>/)[0].trim();

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using String's [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to parse the input string.
Then you may use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to make it a number.

```js
let input = 'Bid</span></td><td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="BID-value" data-reactid="51"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s) " data-reactid="52">0.3000</span>'
let match = input.match(/>([\d.]+)</)
let output = match ? match[1] : undefined

console.log(output, 'as string')
console.log(parseFloat(output), 'as number')
```